# Characteristic of a ring with unity element is the order of the unity element

Tags: ring-theory

prove that "The characteristic of a ring with unity element is the order of the unity element regarded as a member of the additive group"

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What have you done so far?

Comment: What is the definition if not this?

Comment: That's one option for the definition of the characteristic. What definition are you using?

Comment: @Servaes Right, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

The order of the unity element in the additive group of the ring is the least integer $n$ such that $n\cdot1=0$.

But then for any element $a\in\mathcal R$, we have $n\cdot a=n\cdot(1\cdot a)=(n\cdot 1)\cdot a=0\cdot a=0$.

Thus $n$ is also the characteristic of $\mathcal R$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer chris

Comment: how do you know n is the least?